# DNS configuration problem after restarting my computer

Tags: dns, 21.10

Good day everyone,

I had no problem with my internet and browser, when I decided to restart my computer.

And now, Internet is not anymore functioning  (while it does work with other devices)

Browser message says "DNS probe finished bad config". How can I fix this DNS problem?

1. I attempted:
   apt-get purge rdnssd
   apt-get purge resolvconf
   service NetworkManager restart

But, the terminal gives the error message:
E: could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend-open (13:Permission denied)
E: unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

2. I run on the terminal 3 commands:

**1st command: systemctl status NetworkManager**

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendo>

 Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-26 12:24:49 CST; 2h 36min ago
   Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
```

Main PID: 6452 (NetworkManager)

```
  Tasks: 3 (limit: 4216)

 Memory: 6.1M

    CPU: 748ms

 CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
         └─6452 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

Jan 26 13:50:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226619.9205>

Jan 26 13:50:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226619.9214>

Jan 26 13:50:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226619.9219>

Jan 26 13:50:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226619.9225>

Jan 26 13:50:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226619.9242>

Jan 26 13:50:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226619.9256>

Jan 26 13:50:53 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226653.3956>

Jan 26 13:51:04 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226664.8317>

Jan 26 13:51:04 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643226664.8318>

Jan 26 14:44:19 yd-Inspiron-5575 NetworkManager[6452]:   [1643229859.1957>

**2nd command: systemctl status systemd-resolved**

● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; ven>
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-26 10:16:58 CST; 4h 46min ago
   Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
         man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
         https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network->
         https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver>
```

Main PID: 1143 (systemd-resolve)
Status: "Processing requests..."
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4216)
Memory: 8.9M
CPU: 3.839s
CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
└─1143 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Jan 26 15:02:55 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:02:55 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:03:00 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:03:00 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:03:05 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:03:05 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:03:10 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>

Jan 26 15:03:10 yd-Inspiron-5575 systemd-resolved[1143]: Using degraded feature>
lines 1-23

**3rd command: nmcli dev show| grep -i dns**

IP6.DNS[1]:                             ::1

My Ubuntu version is 21.10

thx in advance for your input.

Comment: All three of those commands need superuser privileges in order to work, hence the "permission denied" error message.  However, I'm not sure that purging those packages will resolve anything.  Did you install, remove, or change something before you restarted the computer?

Comment: No. I was using internet, I closed the browser, restarted, and right after no more internet with the DNS error message

Comment: Is there a way to reset the DNS?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1389439/edit) your question with the results of these 3 commands: `systemctl status NetworkManager`, `systemctl status systemd-resolved` and `nmcli dev show | grep -i dns`.

Comment: I just completed the re-edition of the question with commands and results

Comment: It looks like you do not have any DNS server assigned.  Normally this would be assigned by the DHCP on your router.  Did you manually configure an IP to use?  You should probably run the `nmcli dev show` again to see if an IP is assigned.  If so, is the gateway the IP of your router?  Make sure you can successfully `ping` the router.  If you are running the desktop version of ubuntu, you can go into either the network or wifi settings to reset what was changed.

Comment: Late reply due to the covid... Good news, Internet is back. Thx to you Mr. Bovine. For info: After running nmcli dev show, I did not see any problem with IP assignment. I decided to turn on a VPN  program I have on this computer to change the IP. Internet was back. Then, after turning this off, Internet was working  with the regular IP (strangely, when the accident occurred a week ago the VPN program was off).